# Are all the electrons in a white dwarf degenerate?

Tags: white-dwarfs

White dwarfs are supported primarily, if not entirely, by degeneracy pressure from electrons. But are all the electrons degenerate, or are there still some electrons hanging around individual nuclei in white dwarfs made of heavier elements?

Comment: I guess you are excluding near the surface where the pressure is low.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Yes.